# Cross-Compile hsflowd for MIPS -get rid of shared Libraries

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, mips, cross-compiling, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to cross-compile hsflowd for MIPS but can't get rid of shared libraries.

I'm using openwrt toolchain for Atehros MIPS (softfloat, big endian). Program runs on the router but after start i get debug entries:

```
dbg1: dlopen(/etc/hsflowd/modules/mod_pcap.so) failed : Dynamic loading not supported
dbg1: dlopen(NULL) failed : Dynamic loading not supported
dbg1: dlopen(/etc/hsflowd/modules/mod_tcp.so) failed : Dynamic loading not supported
dbg1: dlopen(NULL) failed : Dynamic loading not supported
```

I'm compiling with CFlags: -static -s

Also mod_pcap.o and mod_tcp.o were built before and linked.
So the question is why the program is trying to load dynamic libraries?

Are there any other options to pass to the compiler to build all libraries into the executabels?

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You should remove the `-static` option.

Answer (score 0):

The program is trying to load DLL because it is using explicit dynamic linking. I encountered same problem when building my own program for ARM.

dlopen(NULL) means "get a handle for the program itself", it is useful when one want to dlsym() addresses of symbols that are not in DLLs, but in the program itself.

Unfortunately I did not found no solution despite the fact that it is my own application :(. Static linking (in my case) would require total rethinking of application logic.